# Finding max value in array (array.find)

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, min

Im learning Javascipt and actually im on episode with array methods.
My imaginary exercise relies on found the Max/Min value in array by **array.find** method.

Acutally I did smth like that, but script returned me "Undefined".
Please help. :)

```
const scores = [10, 20, 30, 22, 25, 109, 90];

const maxScore = scores.find(score => {
 let max = 0;
 for (let i=1; i < scores.length; i++){
   if(score[i] > max){
     max = score[i];
   };
 };
  return max;
});
console.log(maxScore);
```

*P.S. I know about "Math.max.apply", but I have to do it by array.find and simple loop.*

Comment: you need to iterate over all items, but find has a short circuit by returning `true`, then it take the actual element as value. the main question, why do you want to take `find` and the second question how do you like to avoid a second loop?

Comment: It is a poor choice to employ `find()` this way for variety of reasons: you don't benefit from  its key feature (exiting loop upon first match) and furthermore, you do nested loop inside of it, so your implementation does O(n²)-time lookup which is unnecessarily slow, whereas single loop is pretty much enough. Would you elaborate a bit on the reasons to do so in order for us to suggest some suitable options?

Comment: A *sensible* `find` function would already *know* the max value, thus it's completely superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it, without using any Array methods, can be written as:

```
const maxScore = (scores) => {
  let score = 0;
  for ( let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++ ) {
    if(scores[i] > score) {
      score = scores[i]
    }
  }

  return score;
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
The find() method returns the value of the first element 
in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.
```

Lets redefine our simple function again,

```
const maxScore = scores => {
  let score = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  scores.forEach(element => {
    let acc = scores.find(number => number > score);
    if(!isNaN(acc)) {
      score = acc;
    }
  })

  return score;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over an index for looping from the end and a temporary max value which is at start undefined and gets the first value from the first element.

Then loop while the value at temp index is smaller than `score`, store this value in `max`, repeat.

At the end return the result if index plus one is equal to the temp index.

This approach takes a single loop. `find` iterates from start of the array and the inner loop from the end of the array if both indices cross, the result is found.

```js
const
    scores = [100, 20, 30, 22, 25, 109, 90],
    maxScore = scores.find(
        ((j, max) => (score, i, array) => {
            if (max === undefined) {
                max = score;
                j = array.length;
            }
            if (score < max) return;
            while (array[j - 1] < score) max = array[--j];
            return i + 1 === j;
        })
        ()
    );

console.log(maxScore);
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` works on each array element. So take the `max` outside the `find` method & `log` `max`. Besides there were two typos

```js
const scores = [10, 20, 30, 22, 25, 109, 90];
let max = 0;
const maxScore = scores.find((score) => {

  for (let i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] > max) {
      max = scores[i];
    };
  };
  return max;
});
console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const scores = [10, 20, 30, 22, 25, 109, 90];

let max = 0;
scores.find(score => { if(score > max) max = score });
console.log(max);
```

Your current code is looping the scores array whilst its already looping it, JavaScripts .find, essentially loops the array.

Comment: `find` is not necessary here, `forEach` would work too.

Comment: of course, but OP said he needs to to use the `find` function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const scores = [10, 20, 30, 22, 25, 109, 90];

scores.reduce(function(a,b) { return a > b ? a : b });
// 109
```